# how can i to access Control in UpdatePanel for Read value controls?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I can't find DropdownList ,Because inside the update panel other control outside update panel can  find it
I using the following code:

```
For Each c As Control In form1.Page.Controls
                findControl(c)
        Next   



Private Function findControl(c As Control)

            For Each k As Control In c.Controls
                If TypeOf k Is DropDownList Then
                    If CType(k, DropDownList).ID = "C1" Then
                        CType(k, DropDownList).SelectedItem.Value = 2
                    End If
                    findControl(k)
                End If
            Next

            Return ""
        End Function
```

////////////////////////////////////

```
<td class="combo_ghaza">
                        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UPC1" runat="server">
                        <ContentTemplate>
                            <asp:DropDownList runat="server" Width="180px" ID="C1"  class="combo_ghaza" EnableViewState="true" Font-Names="myFirstFont" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="C1_SelectedIndexChanged">
                            </asp:DropDownList>

                            <asp:DropDownList ID="CS1"  runat="server" Width="70px"   class="combo_ghaza"  InitialValue="-1" Font-Names="myFirstFont">
                            </asp:DropDownList>
                            </ContentTemplate>
                            </asp:UpdatePanel>

                        </td>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The recursive call seems to be in the wrong position, try to move it one line down

```
Private Function findControl(c As Control)

    For Each k As Control In c.Controls
        If TypeOf k Is DropDownList Then
            If CType(k, DropDownList).ID = "C1" Then
                CType(k, DropDownList).SelectedItem.Value = 2
            End If
        End If
        findControl(k)
    Next

    Return ""

End Function
```